# Google Drive OAuth consent dialog not showing

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm developing an android app that syncs data to Google drive using the REST v3 api. It was working fine and then suddenly it stopped working. The dialog that usually comes up asking for access to Google Drive doesn't show up anymore. I've checked that the SHA1 fingerprint is correct, and I've added the google-services.json file to my project. My project is published to Google Play if that counts for anything.

Here is the connection code:

```
    // Gather credentials
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES)).setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Roblu", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String accountName = settings.getString("accountName", "");
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

    // Start Google services
    HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    service = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("Roblu").build();
```

If I try to sync data, this line will return null:

```
FileList files = service.files().list().setSpaces("appDataFolder").setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").setPageSize(10).execute();
```

Comment: wild guess: Change accountName to something else see if it pops up again.

Comment: I'll give it a shot